# How to recover google chrome passwords from hdd?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, password-recovery

My computer broke and I took out the hard drive to get my data back but chrome refuses to show me my passwords now and that's my passwords for absolutely everything

I have the entire hard drive from the computer that used them so I can't imagine what's missing and I even changed my windows password to the password I used previously in accordance with some other answer but I still get nothing

I desperately need my passwords to do anything on the internet.

Comment: Is the issue when you go to a website it show the password as ***** but you want to know what it is? Or does it show nothing at all, as if you've never been there?

Comment: all usernames for every site is listed but passwords are all blank

Comment: Have you looked in the SQLITE file "Login Data"?

Comment: Looks like Chrome passwords on Linux are stored in various ways based on which desktop manager you use: see [this Chromium doc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/linux_password_storage.md).

Comment: [This Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/a/525062/605262) may help.

Answer (score 3):

[Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html) has a tool named ChromePass. I've used this tool in the past to recover passwords from a old laptop which has crashed.

[image: window]

Comment: I tried chromepass and linked it to the user folder on the external hard drive and provided the password and everything is still blank.

Comment: Strange, it worked when I used it. It was worth a shot.

Comment: This only works on Windows.  I'm looking for a Linux solution.

Comment: Start a new question :)