# Recovering local chrome passwords from dead pc

Tags: encryption, password-management, google-chrome

recently my PC died and will not power on. The motherboard had a complete failure. My HDD survived. I have it set up as an external to pull my photos and such. My question comes down to transferring the local passwords I had stored on chrome. I didn't have a google account sync. But the profiles are still accessible on the old HDD. I want to view my passwords or at least transfer them to my new pc. The older HDD belonged to a win 8.1 pc. I pulled up the Login data sqlite file but when I view it in sql server it says the password value is stored in a blob. Any advice on recovering them would be helpful,a majority of my lifes on there.

Comment: I transferred the file from the old HDD and pasted it into the appdata folders for chrome and tried to browse it via chrome documents from the search bar. It only caused me to download the login data file. I know my older computers password if that helps.

Comment: got the login data file, whats next?

Comment: damn, I wonder if copying all the profile data from the older HDD would work. Any idea on how id view the blob text?

Comment: This really sucks, im not sure what else to do. I back up everything expect passwords.Thanks for your ideas

Comment: If Chrome is not able to load your old profile then there is nothing that can be done.  Having experience in the past dealing with issues like you describe, it should be as transferring the Chrome user profile to your new machine, if that isn't working then nothing can be done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover google chrome passwords from hdd?](https://superuser.com/questions/1129508/how-to-recover-google-chrome-passwords-from-hdd)

Comment: fwiw, i couldn't get an old profile restored from a different disk to work in chrome, but firefox was able to import my chrome profile, and then let me export. go firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered already on SuperUser I believe:
[Recover from external hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1129508/how-to-recover-google-chrome-passwords-from-hdd)

The [Nirsoft Chromepass](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html) software can read passwords on Chrome from an external hard drive if you remember your windows login password. You need this password:

> In order to use this feature, you must know the last logged-on password used for this profile, because the passwords are encrypted with the SHA hash of the log-on password, and without that hash, the passwords cannot be decrypted.

Comment: With Chromepass you need not just the specific Windows user password, but also "Windows Protect folder" for getting encryption keys. If you didn't backup that, you will not see passwords, only usernames.